# How to send one server collectd information to hosted server?

Tags: graphite, grafana, collectd

Am new to graphite monitoring tool. I have one question in this setup. I have two servers and hear one server treated as a hosted server(installed graphite,collectd,statsd and grafana)and it grafana displays the all metrics. In the another second server i have installed the graphite and collectd.Now i would need to send this second server collectd informtion to first server(hosted server)and those metrics information will need to display the web using grafana...

could you please suggest me is there any plugin or any way to setup this configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need graphite on the second host, you can just configure collectd on that host to write to graphite (actually the carbon ingest api) on the first host.

https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_write_graphite

If you do want to have graphite on both servers for some reason, you can use multiple Node entries in your collectd config to have it send metrics to both graphite instances.